# Linq equivalent statement for SQL Inner Join with IN statement

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

```
CREATE TABLE PersonTask
(
PersonId INT NOT NULL,
WeekId INT NOT NULL,
WeekDaysTaskId INT,
WeekEndTaskId INT
)
GO
CREATE TABLE Task
(
Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
[Description] VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
)
GO
INSERT INTO Task(Id, [Description]) VALUES(1, 'Task-01')
INSERT INTO Task(Id, [Description]) VALUES(2, 'Task-02')
INSERT INTO Task(Id, [Description]) VALUES(3, 'Task-03')
GO
INSERT INTO PersonTask(PersonId, WeekId, WeekDaysTaskId, WeekEndTaskId) VALUES(1, 1, NULL, 1)
INSERT INTO PersonTask(PersonId, WeekId, WeekDaysTaskId, WeekEndTaskId) VALUES(1, 2, 2, NULL)
INSERT INTO PersonTask(PersonId, WeekId, WeekDaysTaskId, WeekEndTaskId) VALUES(1, 3, 3, 3)
GO

SELECT 
        PT.PersonId, 
        WeekId,
        'Not on Bench' as [Status]
    FROM PersonTask AS PT
    INNER JOIN Task AS T ON T.Id IN (PT.WeekDaysTaskId, PT.WeekEndTaskId)
    WHERE WeekId = 3/*Param-1*/ and PersonId = 1/*Param-2*/
```

I am trying to write a linq query equivalent to the above T-sql statement but in vain. Can someone please help with C# Linq query to get the above T-SQL statement.

Comment: Ok, are you using EF or Linq-to-SQL? I don't think you can use both (perhaps you meant to use the `linq-to-entities` tag). Plus, are you asking about making the select statement into a LINQ query?

Comment: @IronMan84, Linq-To-SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Must be something like (provided you have a personTaskQueryable and taskQueryable):

```
from pt in personTaskQueryable
from t in taskQueryable
where (t.Id == pt.WeekDaysTaskId || t.Id == pt.WeekEndTaskId)
    && pt.WeekId == 3 && pt.PersonId == 1
select new { pt.PersonId, pt.WeekId, Status = "Not on Bench" }
```

I did not try because I was directly coding in the answer textbox but the Linq documentation says that you cannot do such things with the "join" operator because it only supports equijoins.

The solution is to first build the cartesian product and restrict the result set from there.